# jQuery links to run a function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have a link on my webpage that runs a function: I implement the link with the following:

```
<a href="#" id="reply">Reply</a>
```

And I've created the function like this:

```
$(function reply(){
        $("#reply").click(function(){
         $('#txt').append('sample text');
         return false;
        });
    });
```

But every time I click think link, it goes to the # page instead of running the function.

Comment: Can't repro the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/BwjCb

Comment: You'll need to look at the console and see if you're getting any javascript errors. Your code is correct as written, so something is preventing it from executing.

Comment: If I put www.google.com as the href it takes me to google.com

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: @user2138541 not in my fiddle. **This code is fine;** your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I am implementing the link through another .append. It works when I put the link straight in the body, but if I append it to a div, it no longer works properly

Comment: Your event is not bound when you use the .append method.  You need to bind the event to the div using the $.on() method or manually bind the event after appending the link.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Schleis has the right diagnosis and fix.

Comment: @user2138541 see below for an example of and an alternative to Schleis' fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault();`.

```
$(function reply(){
    $("#reply").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#txt').append('sample text');
       return false;
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7vA3/1/)

**EDIT**

Since you are appending the link to the document the event is not being bound. You can do two things to get an event to bind to a dynamically added element.

1. Put the append *before* the click listener in your code
2. Bind the event using .on();

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "#reply", function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#txt').append('sample text');
   });

   $("#content").append("<a href=\"#\" id=\"reply\">Reply</a>");
   ```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahSBf/1/)